# Highlight jqgrid row by cell value

Tags: jqgrid, selection, highlight

I have a jqGrid showing some data from server (php query, json results).

Is it possible to get the rowid of a specific row knowing the value stored in a column cell and use setSelection to highlight that row?

I try to better explain with an example: 
the users of my application select a value from a dropdown menu using form. 
Then, if this value is in the grid, the row that contains it become highlighted (and, if possible, the grid moves itself to show the highlighted row in the visible portion of the grid window)

Some notes:
The grid pager is configured but all rows are in the first page... so pagination would not be a problem

The highlight/selection acts on only one row a time, no multiselect (at the moment)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this JavaScript function will do the work for you:

```
function check(){
    var data=$('#dropDown option:selected').val();

    var allRowsOnCurrentPage = $('#grid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    //suppose the column you want tho check in dropdown and in grid is "Name"

    for( var i=0;i<allRowsOnCurrentPage.length;i++){
       var Name=getCellValue(allRowsOnCurrentPage[i],'Name');
       if(Name===data){
            jQuery("#grid").setSelection(allRowsOnCurrentPage[i], true);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `allRowsOnCurrentPage.length`?

Comment: oh yes..i picked this code from my working code...let me edit this

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!
I have had to edit a little your function to make it work... here the code that worke:

```
function check() {

   var data=$('#dropDown option:selected').val();
   var allRowsOnCurrentPage = $('#grid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
   for( var i=0;i<allRowsOnCurrentPage.length;i++){
       var Name = $('#grid').getCell(allRowsOnCurrentPage[i], 'Name');
       if(Name===data){
           jQuery("#cetacei_grid").setSelection(allRowsOnCurrentPage[i], true);
       }
}
```